# Grep Individual Commands not working when combined in Multi Pattern grep command

Tags: grep

I have a need to perform multiple grep matches as part of the same grep command. When I run them individually, they work fine. But not when together. I hope someone could either show me a solution or perhaps can help me find a work-around. Here is sample stream:

```
(string start..) RollUp:"V" Enzyme:"ENZA ENZB ENZD ENZE" (..string end)
```

In the first command I am needing to isolate all RollUp substrings.Value is always A or V:

```
grep -o "RollUp:\"[AV]\""
```

In the second command I am needing to isolate all combinations of Enzyme values (1-20 total, spaces in between, don't know values names). This command works:

```
grep -oE 'Enzyme:[[:space:]]*"[^"]+"'
```

However, I need to match both patterns as part of same stream. When I try:

```
grep -oE "RollUp:\"[AV]\""\|Enzyme:[[:space:]]*"[^"]+""
```

, nothing is returned. I would be grateful for any ideas for getting this double grep pattern match to work. Thank you!

Comment: are you looking for `grep -oE 'RollUp:"[^"]+|Enzyme:[[:space:]]*"[^"]+"'` ?

Comment: Possibly. I think I know what you are going for. However, I can't get yours (above) to work. Even the first part by itself (grep -oE 'RollUp:"[^"]+') is not working. Thanks

Comment: Yes! Sorry! I take it back. It does work! Thanks @PS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex `someting[^"]+` : this means string `something` followed by anything till next `"` is seen. Here `+` sign means , at least one or more match.

```
grep -oE 'RollUp:"[^"]+|Enzyme:[[:space:]]*"[^"]+"' file
```